WebdriverIO still logs me in even though the input value is null
I am trying to write a simple test using WebdriverIO on the SauceDemo website. When I insert valid authorization values in the inputs and then clear these inputs, it still somehow logs me in on a button click. Why am I getting logged in even though the input values are cleared?
My test script:
describe("test", () => {
  it("should login to saucedemo", async () => {
    await browser.url("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
    const un = await $('[data-test="username"]');
    await un.setValue("standard_user");
    const pw = await $('[data-test="password"]');
    await pw.setValue("secret_sauce");
    await un.clearValue();
    await pw.clearValue();
    const lg = await $('[data-test="login-button"]');
    await lg.click();
  });
});


seems like the problem is not in the website, as the same script works like it should with playwright
